# C++ : Why it dont work?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to [solve](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum)

In which you have given a array of int and you have to return its sum.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cin >> n;
int k;
vector<int> arr(n);
for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
   cin >> arr[arr_i];
    k = k + arr[arr_i];
    //cout << "arr = " << arr[arr_i] << " k " << k << endl;     //  [0]
    if (arr_i == (n-1))
    {
        cout << k;
    }    

}
return 0;
}
```

This return a afkard no. instead of sum.

But when uncomment out [0] line. code starts working as it should.

P.S. i found out the solution by changing `cout` to `cerr`. 
but wanted to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You use `k` without initialization, which means it will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: oops sorry i forgot to paste it here, i will edit it.

Comment: *"a afkard no"* What does that mean?

Comment: it return a big no. which have no meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the other answer, initialize `k`, move `if` outside of loop

```
vector<int> arr(n);
int k = 0;
for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
   cin >> arr[arr_i];
    k = k + arr[arr_i];
    //cout << "arr = " << arr[arr_i] << " k " << k << endl;     //  [0]    
}
cout << k;
```

as your question, there is no need `std::vector` anymore

```
int sum = 0, num;
for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
   cin >> num;
   sum = sum + num;
}
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Comment: So…you suggest not using the fill constructor? How will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `k` before you use, else it will contain junk value  `int k = 0`;

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers (+1) suggested, you need to initialize `k`. However, I think it is slightly better to assign it the first value initially and reduce the number of iterations therefore:

```
vector<int> arr(n);
if (n > 0) {
    int k = arr[0];
    for(int arr_i = 1;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
        //Your cycle
    }
}
```